# Whats the difference between rename and move?

Tags: windows

In windows console (cmd/command) you can write `rename a b` or `move a b`. Whats the difference between the two?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's two main differences:

1. `rename` cannot move files to another directory or drive, `move` can.
2. `rename` cannot overwrite existing files, `move` can (using the `/y` parameter).

For more information, see the documentation for [`rename`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) and [`move`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move).

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the traditional `cmd.exe` shell:

`rename` cannot move files to a different directory.

```
move *.txt E:\Notes
```

But it can rename multiple files at once. For example:

```
rename very-long-name.c *.cpp

rename *.txt *.lol

rename proj1.* "Project 1.*"
```

*(This works because the MS-DOS `command.com` and Windows `cmd.exe` shells, unlike their Unix counterparts, do not expand wildcards automatically – this is left for the program itself.)*

Answer (score 3):

There are two good answers already, but I'm compelled to mention a difference that hasn't been mentioned yet, and that's the syntax itself. If you want to move a file and you use `rename`, you'll have to put the same name in twice.

```
move MyFile.txt MyFolder
```

versus

```
rename MyFile.txt MyFolder\MyFile.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use `rename` to move files on same drive. `Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.` -- this is from `rename /?`.